# How to use Mongoose Schema required error message in React axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, syntax, custom-error-handling

I have written a message in mongoose Schema required field

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter Your Name"],
    maxlength: [30, "Name cannot exceed 30 characters"],
    minlength: [4, "Name should have more than 4 characters"]
},
fatherName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter Your Father Name"],
    maxlength: [30, "Name cannot exceed 30 characters"],
    minlength: [4, "Name should have more than 4 characters"]
},)}
```

and in React.js I am using axios

```
const registration = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try {

  await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/register', {name: "", fatherName: ""})
  .then(response=>{
    console.log(response)
    console.log("submitted")
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.response.data.message)
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
}
```

}

When I submit this data I get the required error message in String form

> xhr.js:220          POST http://localhost:4000/api/v1/register 400 (Bad Request)
> User validation failed: name: Please Enter Your Name, fatherName: Please Enter Your Father Name

I want these message separatly so that I can use it near to their input filed in frontend

Comment: Mongoose provides the messages separately in the `errors` object, so you need to fix the route handler for `/api/v1/register` and make it return the errors in a JSON response.

Comment: You didn't include the most important part of your code which actually sends the error.